# How to synchronized a canvas with Photon Engine in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, synchronization, photon

I'm trying to synchronize a canvas with photon engine so every player can see it. This canvas will be kind of a tv that any player can turn on and the rest can watch it. I could synchronized a cube adding the PhotonView and the PhotonRigidBody components to the prefab but when I tried the same with the canvas it didn't work at all.
Can anyone tell me what components are required to do this and if it needed it what should I handle with an extra script (i.e transfer ownership).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special about the canvas, but it could be locked in place.

There are two solutions I have for you:

**[Observable Component](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/synchronization-and-state#object_synchronization)**:

You could write a custom observable component, and add it to the PhotonView:

> To make use of this function, the script has to implement the IPunObservable interface.

```
public class CustomObservable : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks, IPunObservable
{
    [SerializeField] PlayerController playerController;

    public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
    {
        if (stream.IsWriting)
        {
            stream.SendNext(playerController.playerNumber);
            stream.SendNext(playerController.playerScore);
        }
        else
        {
            playerController.playerNumber = (int)stream.ReceiveNext();
            playerController.playerScore = (float)stream.ReceiveNext();
        }
    }
}
```

**[Custom Properties](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/synchronization-and-state#custom_properties)**:

You could also use custom properties to sync the data across all players.

> Photon's Custom Properties consist of a key-values Hashtable which you can fill on demand. The values are synced and cached on the clients, so you don't have to fetch them before use. Changes are pushed to the others by SetCustomProperties().

> How is this useful? Typically, rooms and players have some attributes that are not related to a GameObject: The current map or the color of a player's character (think: 2d jump and run). Those can be sent via Object Synchronization or RPC, but it is often more convenient to use Custom Properties.

```
PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.SetCustomProperties(Hashtable propsToSet)
```

You can write a script that uses Photons callback, and updated the UI elements.

```
OnRoomPropertiesUpdate(Hashtable propertiesThatChanged)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the first example to interact with the canvas and I have even less experience with the custom properties. It is possible to handle the synchronization with RPC? I think is the only way of synchronization that I can understand, I could try to create some RPC that let's you interact with the canvas, so when the master client "turn on the tv" It calls and RPC that mimic this action thus everyone will activate it too. Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: @CioCasado yeah, RPCs are fine, and probably well suited for [your use-case](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/synchronization-and-state#infrequent_updates__actions_of_players_).

Comment: I worked! thanks a lot for your answer, at the end I could understand a bit Observable Component and Custom Properties so I would try to use one of the formers if it didn't work!

Comment: Glad it was helpful! :)